# Is there any live video stream editing open source project with API for my needs?

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming

I need an open source project with an API

- capable of reading a live video stream (stream codec can be any API can read - I can provide with practically any live streamable one)
- giving me last image data for some processing (like brightness\contrast or more exotic filtering)
- being able to receive data I've changed and starting to stream that data on to some http://localhost:port/  in some format

I need it to be easily accessible from C# (even better, written in C#).

Answer (score 4):

[FFMpeg.NET](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/) might be a good solution for you.  FFMpeg itself does many conversions.  There is supposed to be a support for advanced filters in the future (maybe even now).  This is a .NET wrapper for it.  The FFMpeg system supports streaming video/audio.

You could also try [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/) which is also open source.