# RTSP video streaming implementation

Tags: c#, implementation, rtsp

I have to write an app in C#. The aplication is a video streaming client-server using rtsp protocol. It is dificult to me to start implementing because i never done before such a big app. If someone could give me some hints or a guideline I will apreciate.

Comment: you need a media server, RED5 or WOWZA could be nice also check this post [Is there any live video stream editing open source project with API for my needs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734099/is-there-any-live-video-stream-editing-open-source-project-with-api-for-my-needs)

Comment: Take a look at VLC and its c# wrappers. You can write your server & client only using VLC Libs. Even if you don't want to use it, It's client interface may help you to diagnose your problems.

Comment: I forgot to say, Create an rtsp server and connect to it with a different VLC instance just using its UI. If you are satisfied you can continue with it.

Comment: i have started like this. I am using VLC as a streaming server and stream a file via UDP. Now i am trying to "translate" the packets that i receive from VLC. But i don;t know how the packets that vlc is sendind look like

Comment: @andrew how did you "translate" the received packets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it yourself if you've never written a networking application before. It's no easy task to write a scalable and robust networking app and it's even harder to implement an existing protocol so that the implementation is fully compatible with the specification. You will fail or end up long over budget.

It will be far easier and cheaper to buy an existing component or integrate an existing server.

Google "streamcoders" for find a library which can handle RTSP.

Answer (score 10):

I have implemented RFC2326 Aka Rtsp in completely managed code.

There is a CodeProject article @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

And the homepage for the library is http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

It took less than 30 days to implement, is completely standards compliant and has draft 2.0 support.

No over budget only over performance. .

Hopefully it helps you!

Comment: Jay, I am a student trying to implement this. I am having some difficulties understanding some concepts would you please help me? kkhalaf at ltu dot edu

Comment: Sure, make a thread on the discussion forum and I will do what I can.

Comment: Thanks. I did on the library's homepage.

Comment: I try to to stream a real file source with your rtsp server, but can not figure out how to do it. It seems that in your example the file you stream is also an rtsp stream. Can not figure out how to add real physical media file (audio.wav) to your rtsp server

Comment: Do you understand that a container (wav in this case) may encompass various codecs? Futhermor that there exists a profile for each such codec which may be encoded or decoded, more simply the file format therein... if you create a discussion on the project page and provide a copy of your file we can explore your needs further at your leisure.

Comment: I do not care codec info.Just want to stream a physical audio file exist on a path.

Comment: To be more clear and if the codec info is really important, lets say 128 Kbps, 8000 Hz, 1 channel, PCM (Little/Signed)

Comment: I answered your question(s) et al, let me know if I did not and thanks for your interest in the project; best of luck.